# Groovy Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>> data manipulation method optimization

Tags: java, groovy

Am trying to update the `Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>> invoices` with the invoiceErrors as below

```
InvoiceError // is an entity with below attributes
{ String errorMessage,
  String invoiceNumber    
}
ErrorMessage                                          invoiceNumber   
-------------                                       -------------------     
File Error : The file is in an unsupported format   INV-Error_Test1
Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported             INV-Error_Test1
Line : 2 MATH ERROR                                 INV-Error_Test1
Line : 3 MATH ERROR                                 INV-Error_Test2
Line : 3 Invoice does not foot Reported             INV-Error_Test2
```

Am trying to achieve below map 
    If the error message doesnt have a line number it need to be appended at the top level as `invLineItems.put('error',['INV-Error_Test1' :`File Error : The file is in an unsupported format`])`
   Otherwise errormessage should be appended to the  matching INVOICE and linenumber as below

```
invLineItems = [INV-Error_Test1:[[LINE:1, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test1, INVOICE_TOTAL:22, error : `Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported`], 
                                [LINE:2, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test1, INVOICE_TOTAL:24, error : `Line : 2 MATH ERROR`],
                INV-Error_Test2:[[LINE:3, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test2, INVOICE_TOTAL:26, , error : `Line : 3 MATH ERROR | Line : 3 Invoice does not foot Reported`], 
                                [LINE:4, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test2, INVOICE_TOTAL:28,]],
                error : [[INV-Error_Test1:`File Error : The file is in an unsupported format`]]
```

I wrote the below method to achieve the above

```
def regex = "^Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?.+";
for (e in invLineItems ){
  def errors =  lipErrors.findAll{it.invoiceNumber==e.key} // finding the error messages with the invoice number
  errors.each{  // fetching the line numbre from error message and finding the matching record the invoice number and line number in invLineItems 
     int lineNumber
     if (it.errorMessage.matches(regex)) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(it.errorMessage);
            if (m.find()) {
                 lineNumber = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
            }
          println "lineNumber = "+lineNumber
        }

    if(e.value['LINE_ITEM_NUMBER'].find{it==lineNumber.toString()}) {
      def data = lipErrors.findAll{it.invoiceNumber==e.key && it.errorMessage.matches("^Line\\s+"+lineNumber+"?\\:\\s+"+lineNumber+"?.+")}
      e.getValue().each{it.put("error", data.errorMessage.join("|"))}

     }   

  }
}
```

The code doesnt look like Groovy and using traditional java code mostly, am wondering whether the code can be simplified with Groovy approach

Answer (score 2):

You can use Groovy's [regular expression operators](http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html) to create Java [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)s.

```
def invoices = [
'LEDES98BI V2',
'LINE|INVOICE_DATE|INVOICE_NUMBER|INVOICE_TOTAL',
'1|20150301|INV-Error_Test1|22',
'2|20150301|INV-Error_Test1|24',
'3|20150301|INV-Error_Test2|26',
'4|20150301|INV-Error_Test2|28,',
'5|20150301|INV WITH WHITESPACE|29,']    

def lines = invoices
    .findAll { it.contains('|') }
    .collect { it.tokenize('|') }

def headers = lines.first()
def invoiceMap =  lines.tail().collect{
    [headers, it].transpose().collectEntries()
}.groupBy{ it.INVOICE_NUMBER }

class InvoiceError {
    String errorMessage
    String invoiceNumber
}

[
    ['INV-Error_Test1', 'File Error : The file is in an unsupported format'],
    ['INV-Error_Test1', 'Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported'],
    ['INV-Error_Test1', 'Line : 2 MATH ERROR'],
    ['INV-Error_Test2', 'Line : 3 MATH ERROR'],
    ['INV-Error_Test2', 'Line : 3 Invoice does not foot Reported']
].collect {
    [['invoiceNumber', 'errorMessage'], it].transpose().collectEntries()
}.collect { it as InvoiceError }
.each {error ->
   def matcher = error.errorMessage =~ /Line : (\d+) (.*)/

   if(matcher) {
       def lineNumber = matcher.group(1)
       def errorDescription = matcher.group(2)
       def line = invoiceMap[error.invoiceNumber]
           .find() { it.LINE == lineNumber }

       if(line.errors) {
           line.errors = "$line.errors |  $errorDescription"
       } else {
           line.errors = errorDescription
       }
   } else {
       if(!invoiceMap.errors) invoiceMap.errors = []
       invoiceMap.errors << [(error.invoiceNumber): error.errorMessage]
   }
}

invoiceMap
```

In this example, I build the InvoiceError instances from a list that's transposed (btw, thank you for that trick). Each resulting map is coerced into an instance of InvoiceError.

I took a different approach by iterating through the errors and inserting them into the invoiceMap, rather than iterating through the invoiceMap and looking up the errors.